# Ejb global transaction management

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb, payara

Is there a way to configure transactions in one "place" in **EJB**? I know that I can use `@TransactionManagement` but it requires adding this annotation to every bean and default transaction attribute is `REQUIRED`. What I want achieve is to disable transaction in whole project. I've tried to create custom annotation using `@Stereotype` but it doesn't work along with `@Singleton`. Then this error occurs:

```
[2019-07-20T08:17:31.918+0200] [Payara 5.191] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=172 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1563603451918] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI definition failure:WELD-001508: Cannot create an InjectionTarget from [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public abstract interface @Stereotype @Singleton @Target @TransactionAttribute @Retention class pl.orangelabs.hod.app.config.NoTransactionComponent as it is an int
erface -- WELD-001508: Cannot create an InjectionTarget from [EnhancedAnnotatedTypeImpl] public abstract interface @Stereotype @Singleton @Target @TransactionAttribute @Retention class pl.orangelabs.hod.app.config.NoTransactionComponent as it is an interface
        at org.jboss.weld.util.InjectionTargets.createNonProducibleInjectionTarget(InjectionTargets.java:82)
        at org.jboss.weld.util.InjectionTargets.createNonProducibleInjectionTarget(InjectionTargets.java:48)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.chooseInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:126)
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.createInjectionTarget(InjectionTargetFactoryImpl.java:88)
```

I'm using `Payara server` to deploy application.

Answer (score 1):

The default Transactionality of EJBs is set, but probably you can avoid the usage of local Ejbs by using CDI-Beans. Define them ApplicationScoped, RequestScoped or SessionScoped if they are somewhat singletons or stateless and use @Inject where you need them.